# Call a WINAPI Function from a shared object(.so) that is loaded into the wine process

Tags: reverse-engineering, wine

I have a windows program that is run under wine. If i understand correctly, the pe-executable is mapped into the wine process.
I use LD_PRELOAD to load a .so into the wine process. This .so hooks into the vulkan rendering pipeline. That makes me able to execute code in the winows program´s main thread.
From there i would now like to call a WINAPI function as if it was called by the windows program. For example GetModuleHandle() from kernel32.dll. But i do not know how to retrieve the address of it.

Is there any possibility to access functions from the dlls that got loaded by wine or windows program?
If i use dl_iterate_phdr the only library i find that seems to have to do with windows is ntdll.so